# stored procedure - Multiple SQL statements

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have SP created in database A, which has multiple SQL texts `(Delete/Insert/Update)` , and part of it , its calling other procedure of database B in try block. If I run locally it works fine, but when I execute SP through `ETL tool` parallel with concurrency , out of 6 calls , 2 or 3 fail randomly saying object of Database B does not exist databaseA.object, Not sure why its happening.

any idea how to resolve? Could it tied to flow of sql statements? How can we ensure that sql statements runs after another? SQL only fails for tied to database B only. ETL makes connection to Database A and since its not failing for all statements ,I do not its authorization issue.

```
Create procedure DB_A_PROC(id varchar)
--
---
as
Try {
sql1 execution on database B (Calling another procedure of database B)
sql2 exeecution on database A (delete)
sql3 execution on database B (Calling another procedure of database B)
sql4 execution on database B (Calling another procedure of database B)
sql5 execution on database A (insert)
sql6 execution on database B (Calling another procedure of database B)
}
catch {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your statements in transactions to make sure they aren't getting executed out of order due to the process running multiple times in parallel.